# jQuery Masonry not Working I can't figure out what's wrong

Tags: jquery, jquery-masonry, masonry

[image: the image shows my results after making all the corrections]I don't know what's wrong with my code, but masonry just seems not to be working. Somebody help! Here's the code i got.

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/masonry/3.3.1/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>    

<div id="shule_left_container">


<script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
       $('.shule_left_container').masonry({
          itemSelector:'.shule',
          isAnimated: true,
        });
       });
</script>


<div id="buffer" style="display: none;"></div>
<div class="shule">1</div>
<div class="shule">2</div>
<div class="shule">3</div>
<div class="shule">4</div>
<div class="shule">5</div>
<div class="shule">6</div>
<div class="shule">7</div>
<div class="shule">8</div>
<div class="shule">9</div>
<div class="shule">10</div>
<div class="shule">11</div>
<div class="shule">12</div>
<div class="shule">13</div>

</div>

</body>
```

//here's the css for the container and the items

```
 .shule{
width:calc(100% / 4 - 5px);/*off-setting margin length*/
float:left;
margin-bottom:10px;
margin-right:5px;
background:#FFF;
}

#shule_left_container{
width:70%;
float:left;
overflow:hidden;
position:relative;
}
```

Comment: Provide a link or make a jsfiddle.

Comment: here's the link: http://plus256.com/stream/

Comment: suprisingly fiddle works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/Wagaba/1o7xLxgt/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem/solution!
I had to load the masonry code in the same function that loads items into the grid container, after the loop!

Thank you all for your contributions.

Comment: I'll continue to tweak in case of anything!

Answer (score 0):

wrong Id in your selector? you have . (class)

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
   $('#shule_left_container').masonry({    // <---- Changed to #shule_left_container
      itemSelector:'.shule',
      isAnimated: true,
    });
   });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I corrected that but it doesn't solve the problem either!

Comment: what could i be missing out here?

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of issues you need to fix. First, typekit needs to be loaded very specifically when using masonry and it is showing an error in the console. See [here for instructions](http://masonry.desandro.com/appendix.html#typekit) on fixing it.
Second, "isAnimated" is not used in the current version of masonry, so use transitionDuration:

```
  $('#feed_container').imagesLoaded(function(){
            $('#feed_container').masonry({
              itemSelector:'.feed',
              columnWidth:'.feed',
              transitionDuration: '0.2s'
            });
          });
```

Thirdly, don't put the above code inside your #feed_container div. Scripts should go at the end of your page if possible.